# Prestashop - Show supplier names instead id

Tags: php, module, admin, render, prestashop

In the list view, i would like show supplier names instead the id. The view is generated automatically. How can I change it?

The code i have in the renderList option is:

```
public function renderList()
{
    $this->addRowAction('view');
    // Adds an Edit button for each result
    $this->addRowAction('edit');

    // Adds a Delete button for each result
    $this->addRowAction('delete');

    $this->simple_header = false;

    return parent::renderList();
}
```

and the field list is the next one:

```
$this->fields_list = array(
        ...
        'id_product_supplier' => array('title' => $this->l('ID Supplier'), 'align' => 'center', 'class' => 'fixed-width-xs'),
        ...
        );
```

If i want show the name of the supplier instead the Id, and have the option to filter for suppliers in the list...

What can i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it in two ways, depending on whose controller is it (yours of default):

If you built your own admin controller:

```
public function getList($id_lang, $order_by = null, $order_way = null, $start = 0, $limit = null, $id_lang_shop = false)
{
    parent::getList($id_lang, $order_by, $order_way, $start, $limit, $id_lang_shop);

    foreach($this->_list as &row)
    {
        $row['new_field'] = 'Hello';
        $row['existing_field'] = 'Changed';
    }
}
```

If you're using a module to modify and existing form:

```
public function hookActionAdminProductsListingResultsModifier($args)
{
    $args['list_total'] += 1;

    foreach($args['list'] as &row)
        {
        $row['new_field'] = 'Hello';
            $row['existing_field'] = 'Changed';
    }
}
```

If you are goona use a hook,  you must register is first. Also, cange the {AdminProducts} part in the hook name.

For more info, see `classes/controller/AdminController.php @ Line 2952`.

```
Hook::exec('action'.$this->controller_name.'ListingResultsModifier', array(
    'list' => &$this->_list,
    'list_total' => &$this->_listTotal,
));
```